# How to avoid out of memory error on Slurm clusters

Tags: linux, hpc, slurm, cgroups

What is the best way to avoid slurm killing a process due to OOM error without running the process multiple times to test out different memory constraints? Is there a soft memory limit that I can set for slurm to dynamically allocate more memory?

The best thing I came up with is to use a large memory limit and allow the process to share the resources, but I was wondering if there are better ways to prevent a process from being killed by OOM error.